# One way sync from Sharepoint to Windows

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-online

I've just uploaded several hundreds of files to my Sharepoint Online libraries. I was wondering what would be the best solution to have them syncronized or kind of a network drive in my WS2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft recommends using the OneDrive Sync client, so here is the [Link to the install instructions from MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2903984/how-to-install-onedrive-for-business-for-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-onl) as a standalone package. Choose the **32-bit version** even if your OS is 64-bit. In my experience with Office rollouts it is still (!) the version giving the least amount of headaches.

Using the OD4B client the files you choose will synchronize to the server. Please note that it is a two-way-sync and if you delete something on the server this will be done in SharePoint as well.

Map to network drive (i.e. via WebDAV) is still possible in SharePoint Online, but it is not reliable and disconnects often due to authentication requirements.